# Dynamically create JavaScript objects with variable depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I'm in trouble with a nasty JSON object that I need to convert to JS object with variable depth.

Shortly: (I'm using jQuery)

```
var nastyJSON_string = "{"generics_utenteID":"1","generics_elencoID":"1","mainbar_ade_stepID_0":"1","mainbar_ade_stepID_1":"3","mainbar_ade_stepTitle_0":"blablabla", "mainbar_ade_stepTitle_1" : "quiquoqua"}";

var nastyJSON = JSON.parse(nastyJSON_string);

// nastyJSON if parsed correctly now is: {generics_utenteID:"1",generics_elencoID:"1" ...and so on}.
```

Now, I need to convert that nastyJSON to a JS object with variable depth. I mean:

```
var reusableJSObject = {
    generics : {
        utenteID : 1,
        elencoID : 1
    },

    mainbar : {
        ade : {
            stepID : {
                0 : 1,
                1 : 3
            },

            stepTitle : {
                0 : "blablabla",
                1 : "quiquoqua"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My best is to create it manually, looping nastyJSON, switch-casing keys and creating objects adding values at the end of the well-known depth.

Like this:

```
jQuery.each(nastyJSON, function(key,value){
    var keysp = key.split('_');
    switch(keysp[0])
    {
        //# generics
        case 'generics':

            if(!reusableJSObject.hasOwnProperty(keysp[0])) { reusableJSObject[keysp[0]] = new Object(); };

            switch(keysp[1])
            {
                //# utenteID
                case 'utenteID':
                    if(!reusableJSObject[keysp[0]].hasOwnProperty(keysp[1])) { reusableJSObject[keysp[0]][keysp[1]]; };
                    reusableJSObject[keysp[0]][keysp[1]] = Number(value);
                break;

                //# elencoID
                case 'elencoID':
                    if(!reusableJSObject[keysp[0]].hasOwnProperty(keysp[1])) { reusableJSObject[keysp[0]][keysp[1]]; };
                    reusableJSObject[keysp[0]][keysp[1]] = Number(value);
                break;
            }
        break;


        //# mainbar
        case 'mainbar':
            if(!reusableJSObject.hasOwnProperty(keysp[0])) { reusableJSObject[keysp[0]] = new Object(); };
        break;

        //... and So On!
    }
});
```

But, what if I do not know at first the nastyJSON structure, and I only know that nastyJSON has keys I had to split and nest until the end of the split?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot change the type of string that has to be parsed (the nastyJSON_string). I must work with keys with "_" in them to indicate a level change in the final js object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery, vanilla JS will do ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/4vjshm42/) is a fiddle):

```
var json = '{"generics_utenteID":"1","generics_elencoID":"1","mainbar_ade_stepID_0":"1","mainbar_ade_stepID_1":"3","mainbar_ade_stepTitle_0":"blablabla", "mainbar_ade_stepTitle_1" : "quiquoqua"}';
var obj  = JSON.parse(json);

function parse(object) {
    var result = {};
    var temp   = {};
    var keys;

    for (var property in object) {
        keys = property.split('_');
        temp = result;

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
            if (typeof temp[keys[i]] == 'undefined') {
                temp[keys[i]] = {};
            }
            temp = temp[keys[i]];
        };

        temp[keys[i]] = object[property];
    }

    return result;

}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(obj)));
```

Output:

```
{
   "generics":{
      "utenteID":"1",
      "elencoID":"1"
   },
   "mainbar":{
      "ade":{
         "stepID":{
            "0":"1",
            "1":"3"
         },
         "stepTitle":{
            "0":"blablabla",
            "1":"quiquoqua"
         }
      }
   }
}
```